# Laravel API - making realtime with Node

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, websocket

We have created an API for an internal applciation we are building, the application has grown way beyond what any of us thought it would, and the next stage is that it now needs to be realtime to be any kind useful.

The API is a RESTful implmentation and is written in laravel. Is there a way to maybe add a Node.js layer to the API which can communicate with websockets on the backbone front end?

I am in unknow territory here so any advice would be great.

Comment: Have a look at [Ratchet](http://www.socketo.me/).  It's written in PHP and I have personally had great success integrating it within a Laravel artisan command to start a web socket server

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be publish an event on something like Redis and have your node app listen for that event and then push down a websocket. Also you could use the node app as a proxy to your api and send information to the websocket that way.